# problem implementing c# decryption client in python

Tags: c#, python, aes

I have a c# client that decrypts an AES encrypted message. I tried to implement the c# logic in my python client, but the result is not the same and is full of question marks and vague characters.

I am using python 3.5 with pycrypto running mint x64.
the code for both c# client and my python version of the code provided below:

c# code:

```
string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212"; 
byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText); //Get the encrypted message's bytes
using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create()) //Create a new AES object
                {
                    //Decrypt the text
                    Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
                    encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
                    encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                            cs.Close();
                        }
                        plainText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                    }
```

my python version:

```
def decode_base64(data, altchars=b'+/'):
    """Decode base64, padding being optional.

    :param data: Base64 data as an ASCII byte string
    :returns: The decoded byte string.

    """
    data = re.sub(rb'[^a-zA-Z0-9%s]+' % altchars, b'', data)  # normalize
    missing_padding = len(data) % 4
    if missing_padding:
        data += b'='* (4 - missing_padding)
    return base64.b64decode(data, altchars)

def decode_message(data, key):
    enc_txt = decode_base64(bytes(data, 'utf-16'))
    salt_t = ["0x49", "0x76", "0x61", "0x6e", "0x20", "0x4d", "0x65", "0x64", "0x76", "0x65", "0x64", "0x65", "0x76"]
    salt = bytes([int(x, 0) for x in salt_t])
    key_bytes = KDF.PBKDF2(key, salt, 32, 1000)
    # iv = enc_txt[:16] // using this line instead of the below line, has no effects on final result
    iv = KDF.PBKDF2(key, salt, 16, 1000)
    cipher = AES.new(key_bytes, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return cipher.decrypt(enc_txt).decode('utf-16')
```

the c# client is working as expected, but my python client is resulting in vague characters and not the actual expected message.

I ran into this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46821018/c-sharp-rfc2898derivebytes-is-working-but-python-pbkdf2-generated-key-and-iv-are?rq=1) 
I think I have a similar problem but I couldn't understand the provided answer.
any answer would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

**UPDATE: C# Server Side Encryption:**
This is the C# server side encryption code as well, i think this question covers multiple aspects of the scenario based on the linked questions and could be a reference for anybody that face the same issues (encodings, encryption, padding...)

```
string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212"; //Declare the encryption key (it's not the best thing to do)
byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText); //Get the bytes of the message
using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create()) //Create a new aes object
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
                encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32); //Set the encryption key
                encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16); //Set the encryption IV

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) //Create a new memory stream
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)) //Create a new crypto stream
                    {
                        cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length); //Write the command to the crypto stream
                        cs.Close(); //Close the crypto stream
                    }
                    cipherText = System.Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray()); //Convert the encrypted bytes to a Base64 string
```

Comment: Have you tried `utf-8`?

Comment: hello there! yes but it was not functional.I had a situation with encodings similar to this  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565896/decrypting-in-python-an-string-encrypted-using-net/10565933)

Comment: It would be helpful if you would post the C# encryption portion to know what the ciphertext looks like (with regard to the BOM). Can only the Python code be changed or also the C# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the Python code the IV is wrongly determined and the code should be changed as follows:

  ```
  keyiv = KDF.PBKDF2(key, salt, 48, 1000)
  key = keyiv[:32]
  iv = keyiv[32:48]
  ```
- In addition, [PKCS7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7) padding is used in the C# code, so that unpadding is necessary in the Python code during decryption. One possibility is [`Crypto.Util.Padding`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/util/util.html#crypto-util-padding-module):

  ```
  import Crypto.Util.Padding as padding

  ...

  decryptedPadded = cipher.decrypt(enc_txt)
  decrypted = padding.unpad(decryptedPadded, 16)  # Pkcs7 unpadding
  return decrypted.decode('utf-16')               # UTF-16LE decoding including BOM-removal
  ```

  In the C# code UTF-16LE ([`Encoding.Unicode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.unicode?view=netframework-4.8)) encoded data are encrypted. The data are preceded by a 2 byte [BOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/encoding/byte-order-mark) (`0xFFFE`). This BOM is automatically removed during UTF-16LE decoding.
- The method `decode_base64` in the Python code seems to have been adopted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9807138/9014097). This method should reconstruct a lost Base64 padding. I'm not quite sure why this should be necessary here. Also the UTF-16 encoding of the ciphertext when calling the method seems pointless to me. Actually a simple Base64 decoding of the ciphertext should be enough:

  ```
  import base64
  ...
  enc_txt = base64.b64decode(data)
  ```

  But maybe there are aspects here that I missed.

Comment: i appreciate your kind and absolutely useful solution, it solved my case. thanks in advance. about the decode_base64 you mentioned, i am totally agree with you. my case is a special one that i do not decrypt the whole received base64 message, but only a portion of it, so it is prone to padding errors.

Answer (score 1):

@Topaco thanks for the explanation and answer.

Pasting the complete code here for those facing the same issue.

```
import base64
import Crypto.Util.Padding as padding
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Protocol import KDF
from pbkdf2 import PBKDF2

def decrypt(data, key):
        enc_txt = base64.b64decode(data)
        salt_t = ["0x49", "0x76", "0x61", "0x6e", "0x20", "0x4d", "0x65", "0x64", "0x76", "0x65", "0x64", "0x65", "0x76"]
        salt = bytes([int(x, 0) for x in salt_t])
        key_bytes = KDF.PBKDF2(key, salt, 32, 1000)
        iv = KDF.PBKDF2(key, salt, 48, 1000)[32:48]
        cipher = AES.new(key_bytes, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        decryptedPadded = cipher.decrypt(enc_txt)
        decrypted = padding.unpad(decryptedPadded, 16)  # Pkcs7 unpadding
        return decrypted.decode('utf-16')        # UTF-16LE decoding including BOM-removal
```